# Compose extension is throwing error : V3 agent not found

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am new to creating Compose Extensions in Teams and am facing an issue when I add it to my Teams.

All the configurations are in place, from registering the Bot to hosting it as a Bot Service on Azure and handling the compose extension query in the code. I have shared the Bot Id in the manifest and given the bot hosted URL with `/api/messages` appended to the endpoint URL.

The bot as a standalone application works locally as well as on the Azure Porta. I have successfully remote debugged it as well. However, as soon as I sideload it in Teams as a messaging extension, the query is not firing appropriately.

1. While typing, it stops and shows "Something went wrong with this app. Try Again".
2. Moreover, when we load the Compose Extension it should make an initial hit to the hosted bot application, I have the debuggers in place and it neither hits the Constructor nor the Post method.
3. I am getting a `404` error saying `V3 agent not found` and a failed POST request.

Anyone who might have faced a similar issue and has recovered from it, or may know where I may be going wrong kindly provide your advice. Highly appreciated.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "f3c14e30-0af2-4f96-b714-5d258edcab47",
  "packageName": "net.azurewebsites.fetchassistant",
  "developer": {
    "name": "abc",
    "websiteUrl": "https://fetchassistant.azurewebsites.net",
    "privacyUrl": "https://fetchassistant.azurewebsites.net",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://fetchassistant.azurewebsites.net"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "FetchAssistant",
    "full": "Fetch Assistant"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "abc",
    "full": "xyz"
  },
  "accentColor": "#235EA5",
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "Microsoft App/Bot Id",
      "scopes": ["personal", "team"],
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "FirstName",
          "description": "Search Relevant Documents",
          "title": "Get Name Division",
          "initialRun": false,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "xyz",
              "description": "Get Name Division",
              "title": "Names"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "validDomains": ["*.microsoft.com", "*.azurewebsites.net"]
}
```

Comment: Could you please try [msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp) sample app and see if you are able to get compose extension working?

Comment: I zipped the Manifest folder. While uploading it as a custom app it is throwing error : Error in parsing Manifest file.

Comment: composeExtensions[0].botId should be the GUID for your bot registered in Bot Framework. Also, validDomains should just be your Azure app domain (foo.azurewebsites.net), not *.azurewebsites.net. You don't need to include *.microsoft.com either.

Give that a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get through the issue you're facing by doing the following:

1. Navigate to https://dev.botframework.com/bots/
2. Click on the Microsoft Teams icon in the "Add a featured channel" section
3. Register your app

Comment: Could, you, please check if it still works. I don't even have "Add a featured channel" section when I go to the link that you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error myself on an extension.
Following the idea of adding channels, I went to the channels section.
[image: Notice, there's no Teams]

There was no Teams channel configured.

So, I added it.
[image]

And the error went away as my extension loaded.