# MS Teams Messaging Extension submitTask failing with "v3 agent not found" error

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm creating my first Microsoft Teams extension.  For now I'm just trying to get the basic plumbing for a messaging extension working.  I'm trying to build an extension which will allow a user to search for content in my service and then return a card into their compose window in personal and Teams chats.

I've tried to follow the basic guide ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/create-messaging-extension ) for creating a messaging extension using App Studio.  I've setup a bot as it describes, and I have built a dummy echobot endpoint for the bot (using Ruby).  I am able to "chat" with my bot directly in the Teams client and it is able to respond.

My messaging extension defines an action based command with a taskInfo with a web view URL to render and a fetchTask set to false.  I've written a basic static HTML page for this and included the teams-js library.  The web view loads and the teams-js library initialization callback is called.  I have a submit button which calls microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask which as I understand it, should be calling my bot with a "composeExtension/submitAction" message to which I would respond with the card. (Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=json )

I've tried installing my extension in Teams through the "Upload a custom app" option both as a "for me and my teams" and "for " but still have the following issues.

When I open my extension in the Teams client from the compose area and click this submit button in my iframe content, the submit I get a "Unable to reach app. Please try again" error displayed.  In the dev console, I can see that the response to the "invoke" http post is {"errorCode":404,"message":"V3 agent not found."}

No traffic is actually sent to my bot during any of this process.

I saw this older post - [Compose extension is throwing error : V3 agent not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482310/compose-extension-is-throwing-error-v3-agent-not-found) .  The https://dev.botframework.com/bots/ it refers to seems to be outdated, but in the Azure "Bot Channels Registration" console, I have gone to Channels and added "Microsoft Teams" (which I believe is the new equivalent).

Has anyone seen this happen and figured out what was going on?  Much thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're using the correct id for the submitTask command? It needs to be the AppId as per the Azure App for the Bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilton had the right answer.

I had grabbed the Subscription ID from the Bot Channels Registration page instead of the App ID from the Azure Active Directory -> Apps Registration page and used that in the messaging extension manifest as the "botId" in the composeExtensions array.  After fixing that I'm now getting messages submitted to my bot backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for composeExtension/submitAction for Bot SDK V3. Make sure you pass the bot id and command text in taskInfo object.

```
 case "composeExtension/submitAction":
                    string commandid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.TaskModuleSubmitData<string>>(activityValue).commandId;
                    taskInfo = GetTaskInfo(commandid);
                    taskEnvelope = new Models.TaskEnvelope
                    {
                        Task = new Models.Task()
                        {
                            Type = Models.TaskType.Continue,
                            TaskInfo = taskInfo
                        }
                    };

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, taskEnvelope);
```